# Memory error when asking for the count of a NSMutableArray instance

Tags: objective-c, memory, error-handling, count, nsmutablearray

```
arrayOfBookViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
BookView *book1 = [[BookView alloc] init];
[arrayOfBookViews addObject:book1];
BookView *book2 = [[BookView alloc] init];
[arrayOfBookViews addObject:book2];
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfBookViews);
NSLog(@"%@",arrayOfBookViews.count);
```

Running this code gives me:
(
    "",
    ""
)
which is due to the second last line. The last line then throws me a exc_bad_access memory error. Since the array as well as its objects are properly allocated and initialized, I don't see why asking for the count of the array should give me a memory problem. I'm currently using automatic reference counting in this program with xcode 4.

Please explain why the last line in the code produces a memory error. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it is causing the memory leak but arrayOfBookViews.count returns an int, try %i instead of %@.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayOfBookViews.count` returns an `NSUInteger`. `NSUInteger` is not an object, its a primitive. The `%@` format specifier just calls `description` on the object passed to it, so you tried to call a method on a primitive which is invalid.

Change the log to `NSLog(@"%d",arrayOfBookViews.count);` and you'll get your result you wanted.

Comment: omg what a silly mistake on my part. thank you guys so very much.

Comment: You need a cast to make that completely safe.

Answer (score 0):

You trying to print `int` value. Use `%d` for this:

```
NSLog(@"%d",arrayOfBookViews.count);
```

Comment: If you want to be safe, you should cast the count to `int` because on 64 bit NSUInteger is `unsigned long`

Comment: If you have an array with enough objects for this to matter you have bigger issues.

Comment: @JeremyP, thanks for correct, yes, i know this. I just say it for `%d` format which commonly used with `int` type.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the return type of NSArray's `-count` method.  You'll find it is an `NSUInteger` which is a typedef to `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` which is a standard C type.  You should be using `%u` or `%lu` in the format specifier.